# Discord.py tasks.loop does not work and it returns no errors

Tags: python, loops, discord.py

I've been trying to make loops in Discord.py, but I keep failing. What makes it harder is that it returns no errors.

This is the code;

```
import discord
import datetime
import time
import threading
import os
import json
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext.tasks import loop
import keep_alive

prefix = "s."
token = str(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = prefix)
client.remove_command("help")
os.chdir(r".")
ownerId = [219567539049594880]
logChn = 705181132672729098
secondsUp = 0

@loop(seconds=1)
async def add_second():
    secondsUp+=1
    print("+1 Second")
```

The console does not print anything. No errors. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried starting the client?

Comment: It is in the code below, this is just the top.

Comment: please specify a code that contains something that should work (in this case, all of it)

Comment: the whole code is 439 lines long. The bot works and functions correctly. It processes commands and events. I am stuck on creating a loop though.

Comment: did you call add_seconds.start()

Comment: Also try commenting out your `secondsUp+=1` (or passing as a parameter), my python 3.8 stops at that statement and doesn't raise an exception. Loop then runs fine with the `.start()` in my `on_ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.py, you must call the  `.start()` method on every loop that you create. In this case, `add_seconds.start()`. Also, try adding `global secondsUp` to the top of your function definition.